# summing up only non NaN Data in timeseries with python

Tags: python, sum, pandas, time-series, nan

I need the sum of daily values, but only from the days, that doesn't contain NaN values. My csv File contains half hourly data but sometimes, the measurement device fail. I need the daily sums but as soon as it contain a NaN value, I don't want it, to sum this day up. 
 My Csv file looks like that:

```
date        time       ET
28. Nov 01  08:15   -0.00152
28. Nov 01  08:45   -0.00324
28. Nov 01  09:15   0.00805
28. Nov 01  09:45   0.00684
28. Nov 01  10:15   0.00918
28. Nov 01  10:45   
28. Nov 01  11:15   0.00867
28. Nov 01  11:45   0.01014
28. Nov 01  12:15   0.01697
28. Nov 01  12:45   0.00739
```

On this day is one missing value so I don't want the sum for this day, but for all other days which have all measurement values.

My current code is this:

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.read_csv('C:\Python27\Scripts\ET_T_2000.csv', sep=';', parse_dates=[['date', 'time']])
ts.fillna(0)
ts1 = ts.set_index('date_time')['ET'].resample('D', how='sum')
```

Does anybody have an idea how to do it?

Comment: [`nansum`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/pandas.core.nanops.nansum)? I don't actually know pandas, but it looks like the tool to use.

Comment: you can try converting nan to 0 and then sum it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to filter out all the data from any days that contain a NaN, and then sum the days with a complete, NaN-free data set.

For simplicity make it a Series, not a DataFrame, by using the `squeeze` keyword. (This is not essential, but it makes what follows a little more direct.)

```
et = pd.read_csv(..., index_col=0, squeeze=True)
```

To filter out days with any NaNs,

```
complete_days_only = et.groupby(lambda x: x.date).filter(lambda x: ~x.isnull().any())
```

And now resample

```
complete_days_only.resample('D', how='sum')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I get Errors: If I drop the "parse_dates=[['date', 'time']]" in the "pd.read.csv..." line, the Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'date' occurs. If I don't drop it, the Error: AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'filter' occurs.

Comment: "``SeriesGroupBy`` has no attribute ``filter``" means you're using an old version of pandas without filter. Update your installation of pandas if you can; otherwise dig through my old answers for a workaround using ``transform``. (I answer filter questions on here a lot.)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you want to use:

`ts.dropna()`